# Tomcat rewrite URL

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8

I am trying to rewrite all requests to a server that come in on a specific port to a specific folder:

```
http://tomcatserver:8090/query -> http://tomcatserver:8090/folder/query
```

The folder itself should not have any redirection applied:

```
http://tomcatserver:8090/folder -> http://tomcatserver:8090/folder
```

What I came up with until now is this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/folder(/|$)
RewriteRule (.*) /folder$1 [L]
```

If anyone knows why this is not working, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I have never configured it on Tomcat, but have quite a lot of experience from configuring rewrites on Apache HTTPD, so I would try to use `RewriteRule ^/(.*) /folder/$1 [L]`.

Comment: Nope - it seems it's ending up in a loop... Also the name of the folder that hosts the application is also the name of the server - and to put a name on it, it's Jira. So, just to explain everything: jira.domain.com:8090 should be directed to jira.domain.com:8090/jira...